# How can I deactivate all the materials before rendering in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I made a scene which I now need to render, for testing purposes; is it possible for me to deactivate all the materials without having to loose them? As in hiding them in the render.

Answer (score 8):

You can assign a single material to the whole layer. The original materials will remain assigned to your objects but will be ignored at render time and will be replaced by the material specified on this setting.

[image]

Comment: how to do this in blender v2.90 ?